# Refactoring to workspace structure causes extern crate imports to not work

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I need different parts of my project to use different versions of the same extern crate so I'm refactoring my Rust project to be divided into multiple packages via the workspaces system using [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1525-cargo-workspace.md) as a guide. Doing so is causing all my pub extern crate imports to not work.

This post is very similar to one I created very recently and then deleted - this version contains a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Here's my project structure

```
workspace_test/
  root/
    src/
      main.rs
    Cargo.toml
  Cargo.toml
```

workspace_test/Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "workspace_test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Phoenix <kahlo.phoenix@gmail.com>"]

[workspace]
members = [
    "root"
]

[[bin]]
name = "root"
path = "root/src/main.rs"
```

workspace_test/root/Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "root"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Phoenix <kahlo.phoenix@gmail.com>"]

[dependencies]
time = "0.1"
```

workspace_test/root/src/main.rs:

```
pub extern crate time;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

[This is also on github](https://github.com/gretchenfrage/ws_problem), so it can easily be cloned and `cargo run`'d.

This is the error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `time`
 --> root/src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | pub extern crate time;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `workspace_test`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `workspace_test/Cargo.toml` you create a package with the binary `root`. If you execute `cargo run`, it runs the `main.rs`, but since you didn't state the dependencies in this manifest file, the error occurs. The dependency is only specified in `workspace_test/root/Cargo.toml`, which is not used at this point.

I assume you want to use the workspaces proposed by the RFC. You can create a workspace with virtual manifests, which must neither specify a `[package]` nor `[[bin]]`, so just remove them. `workspace_test/Cargo.toml` now looks like this:

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "root"
]
```

If you only have one executable, you can now pass the package: `-p/--package`

```
cargo run -p root
```

or specify the manifest path manually:

```
cargo run --manifest-path root/Cargo.toml
```

If `root/Cargo.toml` contains multiple targets, you can just append the `--lib` or `--bin` flags as usual. E.g. this would execute the `abc`-binary specified in `workspace_test/root/Cargo.toml`:

```
cargo run -p root --bin abc
```