# How to deal with multiple nested workspace roots?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How can you have multiple nested workspace with Cargo?

I have the following project structure:

```
myworkspace
├── project_a
│   └── Cargo.toml
├── project_b
│   └── Cargo.toml
│   └── project_b_dependency
|       └── Cargo.toml
└── Cargo.toml
```

Where `project_b_dependency` is a big library which is a git submodule which has a workspace by itself.

I get an error when I run `cargo build` because there is a workspace within a workspace.

```
$ cargo build
error: multiple workspace roots found in the same workspace:
  /myworkspace
  /myworkspace/project_b/project_b_dependency
```

Is there a simple work-around? I want to keep `project_b_dependency` in source control as a submodule.

This is not a duplicate of [Refactoring to workspace structure causes extern crate imports to not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712872/refactoring-to-workspace-structure-causes-extern-crate-imports-to-not-work) because I want to know how I can deal with nested workspaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refactoring to workspace structure causes extern crate imports to not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712872/refactoring-to-workspace-structure-causes-extern-crate-imports-to-not-work)

Comment: What do you want the behavior to be? Should `cargo build --all` put all the build artifacts of the workspace members of `project_b_dependency` into the `myworkspace` target directory?

Comment: Yes, that's the behavior I desired. Thankfully, everyone was able to answer my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that nested workspaces are quite difficult to manage, so
one possibility is to change the layout of you project:

```
.
├── myworkspace
│   ├── Cargo.lock
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── project_a
│   │   ├── Cargo.toml
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── lib.rs
│   ├── project_b
│   │   ├── Cargo.toml
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── lib.rs
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
└── project_b_dependency
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── lib.rs
```

in `myworkspace/Cargo.toml`:

```
[workspace]
members= ["project_a", "project_b"]
```

In `myworkspace/project_b/Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
project_b_dependency = {path = "../../project_b_dependency"}
```

I've tried to use `workspace.exclude` property with your layout but without success.

Comment: Does that mean that the workspace `project_b_dependency` can only be imported all at once? Or can I import only one of its crates?

Answer (score 7):

Workspaces can't be nested; as [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section) state:

> A crate may either specify package.workspace or specify `[workspace]`.
>   That is, **a crate cannot both be a root crate in a workspace (contain
>   `[workspace]`) and also be a member crate of another workspace** (contain
>   `package.workspace`).

The Cargo [workspace RFC](https://github.com/nox/rust-rfcs/blob/master/text/1525-cargo-workspace.md#validating-a-workspace) also specified this:

> A workspace is valid if these two properties hold:
>
> - **A workspace has only one root crate (that with `[workspace]` in `Cargo.toml`)**.
> - All workspace crates defined in `workspace.members` point back to the workspace root with `package.workspace`.

Comment: Since this post, it's currently possible as [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section) now state. Also : `An empty [workspace] table can be used with a [package] to conveniently create a workspace with the package and all of its path dependencies.`

Comment: I don't see that phrase in the docs. It explains two examples a workspace with a package in the root, and a workspace that has a virtual root with (possibly) multiple children... but it doesn't mention further nesting. i.e. those children being workspaces with children of their own. The existence of this issue in the open state seems to confirm that? https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5042

Answer (score 1):

I find a method to keep git submodule.

1. Add submodule project's workspace members to parent Cargo.toml
2. Remove submodule project's Cargo.toml
3. Use submodule_name/crate path to define dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do this one, but it requires cooperation for the submodules you are bringing in to follow a similar pattern.

My issue here was that I had a lib `bigger_lib` which is in the repo as a workspace, and then a `common_lib` which is a dependency for both `my_app` and `bigger_lib` (not specifically what the question was asking, but what I'm  trying to solve). These are representative our current state of many little workspace repos, all on git.

With a layout like this

```
workspace root
├── Cargo.toml (workspace)
├── my_app (executable)
|   └── Cargo.toml
├── common_lib (lib, via submodule)
|   └── Cargo.toml
└── bigger_lib_repo (workspace, via submodule)
    ├── Cargo.toml  (workspace)
    ├── common_lib (lib, via submodule)
    |   └── Cargo.toml
    └── bigger_lib (lib, not a submodule)
```

With content looking like this

```
# ./Cargo.toml
[workspace]

members = ["app"]

# Important to avoid the multiple workspaces error
exclude = ["bigger_lib_repo"]

# Unsure if this is necessary
resolver = "2"

[patch.crates-io]
# The common dep gets overridden for everybody here
common_lib = { path = "./common_lib" }
```

```
# ./my_app/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "my_app"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
# Note this isn't specced using a path
common_lib = { version = "0.1.0" }
bigger_lib = { version = "0.1.0", path = "../bigger_lib_repo/bigger_lib" }
```

```
# ./bigger_lib_repo/Cargo.toml
[workspace]

members = [ "bigger_lib" ]

resolver = "2"

[patch.crates-io]
# Same as the root workspace
common_lib = { path = "./common_lib" }
```

```
# ./bigger_lib_repo/bigger_lib/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "bigger_lib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
# Note this isn't specced using a path
common_lib = { version = "0.1.0" }
```

All other `Cargo.toml` files are not particularly different from what you'd expect.

With this pattern I can

- Build the workspace root without issues
- Build the nested workspace root without issues
- Use publicly exported package members from nested libraries (ie: `bigger_lib::common_lib::MyStruct`)